# Context path routing in Tomcat ( service swapping )

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

Here is what I would like to achieve:

I have a web service A which I want to be able to deploy side by side with other web services of type A - different version(s). For now I assume 2 instances side by side. I need it because the service has a warm up stage, which takes some time to build up stuff from DB and only after it is ready it can start serving requests ...

I was thinking to deploy to Tomcat6 context paths like: *"/ServiceA-1.0"*, *"/ServiceA-2.0"*
and then have a "virtual" context like *"/ServiceA"* which will point to the desired physical service e.g. *"/ServiceA-1.0"*. So external world will know about ServiceA, but internally, my ServiceA related stack would know about versioned ServiceA url ( there are more components involved but only ServiceA is serving outer world ). When new service is ready, I would just reconfigure the "virtual" context to point to a new service.

So far, I was not able to find out how to do this with Tomcat and starting to tkink it is not possible. I found suggestions to place Apache Server in front of Tomcat and do the routing there, but I do not want to enroll another piece of software unless necessary.

My questions are:
- is this kind of a "virtual" context and routing possible to do with Tomcat6?
- any other options, wisdom and lessons learned how to achieve this kind of service swapping scenario?

Best,
Jozef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the warm up period that you mention I assume that you want more or less uninterrupted service when you switch implementations. This really is easy to handle with an Apache in front.

I typically enjoy the flexibility I get from this extra layer. Apache is not too invasive on your system. Plus - if you run on unix - it's trivial (read: default) to have Apache listen on port 80 while you'll have to go extra miles to make tomcat listen on port 80 *and not run as root*.

If you have never touched Apache, be assured that it's easy to learn in short time. Especially when you don't need the full power that it brings. Configuring a reverse proxy (or mod_jk) is well documented everywhere. And the feature you mention is a hybrid of reverse proxy and load balancer - even if you only have one server to balance the load "between", you'll have two different contexts/versions.

Don't fear the Apache, you're on the right path :)

Comment: Yes, Apache indeed feels about right for the task and I am not afraid of it at all. But I will have to convince admins to enroll it to the cluster, which I most probably should try hard ... I just want to scan other options as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall offhand if Tomcat has a native ability to do this, but you should be able to accomplish what you are looking for fairly easily with a simple web app servlet.  Basically create a servlet that listens to "/ServiceA" and redirects everything to the URL that you need.  You can create a simple admin page (use a valve to control access to it?) or a JMX service to control the endpoint where you want to redirect.

Not as simple as using something like [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/) or [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) in front, but likely just as effective, and allows you to keep everything within Tomcat if that's really what you want.

[Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound) is also a very fast/lightweight load balancer that you would be able to run in front of your service, but if memory serves, it cannot change configuration on the fly; it has to be stopped and restarted.  However, it is lightning fast to stop and start or send a SIGHUP, so it shouldn't be too painful.  Of course, this does mean a separate binary that you must run/configure/support in addition to Tomcat.

I was just rereading your original question and realized that no one answered your question about caveats with switching services.  You don't indicate if your service is stateless or not, but you need to worry about/consider the impact of losing sessions/states when switching between the two services.  Outside of that, I would expect the impact to be minimal.

Comment: By redirect you mean back to client redirect? That would be performance penalty for me. However I was experimenting with dispatching from one webapp to other one (forward, include) but hit some roadblock with re-executing filters + jsp pages serving

Comment: Actually, I was thinking more along the lines of a RequestDispatcher (ie: more of a server-side redirect).  Using client side redirect would somewhat defeat the purpose as you would be exposing your "private" url and it would definitely be a performance and load hit on your machine.  Of course, you would basically be building a minature version of a reverse proxy.  I am editing my answer to include another very lightweight load balancer that you would be able to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 supports versioning out of the box. You just deploy e.g. Service##1.war, Service##2.war, etc, and they all appear as /Service, and the latest one in existence is the default, or you can talk to a specific version. Front-end this with an Apache HTTPD running mod_proxy and you're done. I would recommend mod_proxy_ajp rather than mod_proxy_jk, as it's much easier to configure and doesn't appear to lack any features to me.

Comment: hmm ... context versioning, interesting indeed. could be a solution, however I am forced to use Tomcat 6 (have edited question)